# Requested method in webapi controller doesn't support get

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I get this error

```
{
    "message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8227/api/history/2019211/history'.",
    "messageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'History' that matches the request."
}
```

But I have the action method as below.

```
[HttpGet, Route("history")]
public IHttpActionResult GetHistory(string iD)
{
      var req = historyReq.From(iD);            
      return Ok(Convert.From(req));
}
```

Please remember, it works for all other modules and places, but this.

I suspect it is due to some ordering? As this controller has another method with HTTPPost and same route. Will that be a problem? But name of that method is different which is UpdateHistory

Comment: can you post your route configuration? And try not to mark both of the `HTTP` methods,explicitly specify either `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Sorry mate, I have the correct attributes, it works for all other controllers but this. And that too only this action. I have a post action which gets hits perfectly fine. I can post you the route config though.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Mate, both controllers use same default webapi config, I do not see an issue there as well.

Comment: Inform about the routing defenition and about the request creation. I'm feeling something itchy on the url `/api/history/2019211/history` but we are not witch's we need more information.

Comment: Shouldn't your request be - http://localhost:8227/api/history/history?id=2019211

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the GET method correctly?

Here is an example I am currently working on and it works fine.

```js
 [RoutePrefix("api/subsection")]
    public class SubSectionController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("subsectionslist")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetSections(int sectionId)
        {
            using (var db = new StudyHubContext())
            {
                var model = db.Section.Where(x => x.SectionId==sectionId)
                    .Include(x => x.SubSection)
                    .Select(x => x.SubSection)
                    .ToList();
                return Json(model);
            }

        }
```

This is how I call this (simply paste this into the web browser)

http://localhost:60552/api/subsection/subsectionslist?sectionId=1

Have you a number of get methods? If so you can supply a dummy parameter but the route should be unique to each controller action method.

Comment: I have everything correct as per other methods and controllers. The same method (Similar gets) in other controllers with custom name works and fetches me data. The problem is, this action method is not being hit in this controller. Why? I have evrrything same config

Comment: I would put a break point on all action methods in that controller and see if it hits a different action method